# Why Solana RPC write Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly?

Tags: python, solana

I tried to copy my token swap transaction. And I get an error:

> solana.rpc.core.RPCException: {'code': -32602, 'message': 'invalid
> transaction: Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets
> correctly'}

Successful Transaction - https://solscan.io/tx/5yL5MnDyLmDGu3xeR4gz8y3pJWGg5qXTzxMgd9qUPgYsPQ5ZUPkJt1DVHkmRAoqZUenHtDqgb4vsfkC1P2vjmKW9

Code:

```
from solana.transaction import AccountMeta, Transaction, TransactionInstruction
from solana.rpc.types import TxOpts
from solana.account import Account
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.rpc.commitment import Recent, Root
from solana.keypair import Keypair
import base58
from spl.token.instructions import transfer, TransferParams

url = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com'
client = Client(url)

txn = Transaction(recent_blockhash=client.get_recent_blockhash()['result']['value']['blockhash'], fee_payer='8noB4Wv7rpUsz17eRD833G7VHnnmfp1JdstyXzuDvfoY')


byte_array = base58.b58decode('myprivatekey')
keypair = list(map(lambda b: int(str(b)), byte_array))[:]

account = Keypair(keypair[0:32])

txn.add(
    TransactionInstruction(
        keys=[
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('6vdR9SgRuBtdiR6rgpXLcdjQgV7Ja7GtjqjL5EP3uQwK'), is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('8noB4Wv7rpUsz17eRD833G7VHnnmfp1JdstyXzuDvfoY'), is_signer=True, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('Dv3UEMWoX4zwviYDG1ZpdBNiNjmUbkoAmohZLPar3oyA'), is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('2vfgEPJStq761qrkyh8xedrj9zpew1GQ8CobjtQ4wtyM'), is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('2x3yujqB7LCMdCxV7fiZxPZStNy7RTYqWLSvnqtqjHR6'), is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('2x3yujqB7LCMdCxV7fiZxPZStNy7RTYqWLSvnqtqjHR6'), is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('6UzTmTpFt8pEbdAnstJrusWU1eWggPrNRsyjr9XaPVTX'), is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('JD8dd73w3JigdsS7rKCqpVzFhzRXZcK2evZzxFURd21x'), is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('FoXyMu5xwXre7zEoSvzViRk3nGawHUp9kUh97y2NDhcq'), is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('2GUvz8bAtoeartcAPYifiBWjSVobjEF7jp7uC2cELMCx'), is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL'), is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA'), is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('11111111111111111111111111111111'), is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=PublicKey('SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111'), is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
            
        ],
        program_id=PublicKey('8BYmYs3zsBhftNELJdiKsCN2WyCBbrTwXd6WG4AFPr6n'),
        data=bytes.fromhex('5052c1c9d81b46b801000000000000001027000000000000')
    )
)


inner_instruction_transfer = txn.add(transfer(TransferParams(
    amount=1,
    dest='JD8dd73w3JigdsS7rKCqpVzFhzRXZcK2evZzxFURd21x',
    owner='6vdR9SgRuBtdiR6rgpXLcdjQgV7Ja7GtjqjL5EP3uQwK',
    program_id='TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
    source='6UzTmTpFt8pEbdAnstJrusWU1eWggPrNRsyjr9XaPVTX',
)))


from solana.system_program import TransferParams, transfer
inner_instruction_sol_transfer = txn.add(transfer(TransferParams(from_pubkey='8noB4Wv7rpUsz17eRD833G7VHnnmfp1JdstyXzuDvfoY', to_pubkey='Dv3UEMWoX4zwviYDG1ZpdBNiNjmUbkoAmohZLPar3oyA', lamports=9800)))

inner_instruction_sol_transfer2 = txn.add(transfer(TransferParams(from_pubkey='8noB4Wv7rpUsz17eRD833G7VHnnmfp1JdstyXzuDvfoY', to_pubkey='2x3yujqB7LCMdCxV7fiZxPZStNy7RTYqWLSvnqtqjHR6', lamports=200)))



txn.sign(account)
rpc_response = client.send_transaction(
    txn,
    account,
    opts=TxOpts(skip_preflight=True, skip_confirmation=False)
)

print(rpc_response)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is going to be from the second instruction that you're adding:

```
inner_instruction_transfer = txn.add(transfer(TransferParams(
    amount=1,
    dest='JD8dd73w3JigdsS7rKCqpVzFhzRXZcK2evZzxFURd21x',
    owner='6vdR9SgRuBtdiR6rgpXLcdjQgV7Ja7GtjqjL5EP3uQwK',
    program_id='TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
    source='6UzTmTpFt8pEbdAnstJrusWU1eWggPrNRsyjr9XaPVTX',
)))
```

The owner of the account in the second instruction, `6vdR9SgRuBtdiR6rgpXLcdjQgV7Ja7GtjqjL5EP3uQwK` must sign this transaction for it to be valid.  Currently, only `account` is signing, which I'm guessing is `8noB4Wv7rpUsz17eRD833G7VHnnmfp1JdstyXzuDvfoY`.